# Chained Many To Many Field não retorna valores

Tags: django, django-admin

Segue abaixo imagem da tela de cadastro onde deveria aparecer opções para escolhas
[image: Ao selecionar Feição deveria aparecer opções nos campos Possíveis Causas e Prováveis consequências]

A baixo imagem contendo as opções que deveriam aparecer na imagem acima
[image: As opções selecionadas deveriam estar presentes na tela anterior]

segue o código do model.py

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
from djgeojson.fields import PointField
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point
from django.contrib.gis.geos import GEOSGeometry
from django.contrib.gis.gdal import SpatialReference, CoordTransform
# from bdg import models as bdg_models
from django.contrib.gis.measure import D
import django_tables2 as tables
from sorl.thumbnail import ImageField
from rest_framework import serializers
from smart_selects.db_fields import ChainedManyToManyField
from django.contrib import messages
from django.shortcuts import render
from .thumbs import ImageWithThumbsField
from sorl_thumbnail_serializer.fields import HyperlinkedSorlImageField
from drf_dynamic_fields import DynamicFieldsMixin
from django.core.validators import FileExtensionValidator
import zipfile

class Causa(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome

class Consequencia(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome

class Feicao(models.Model):
    # Opcoes Tipo
    acesso_irregular = "Acesso irregular"
    acumulo_sedimentos_pista = "Acumulo de sedimentos sobre a pista"
    alagamento = "Alagamento"
    assoreamento = "Assoreamento"
    atropelamento_animais_silvestres = "Atropelamento de animais silvestres"
    deslizamento = "Deslizamento"
    erosao = "Erosão "
    estrutura_abandonada = "Estrutura abandonada"
    falta_de_vegetacao = "Falta de vegetação"
    lixo_residuos_solidos = "Lixo e resíduos sólidos"
    ocupacao_irregular = "Ocupação irregular"
    outros = "Outros"
    queda_bloco = "Queda de bloco"
    recalque = "Recalque"

    tipos_opcoes = (
        (acesso_irregular, "Acesso irregular"),
        (acumulo_sedimentos_pista, "Acumulo de sedimentos sobre a pista"),
        (alagamento, "Alagamento"),
        (assoreamento, "Assoreamento"),
        (atropelamento_animais_silvestres, "Atropelamento de animais             silvestres"),
        (deslizamento, "Deslizamento"),
        (erosao, "Erosão "),
        (estrutura_abandonada, "Estrutura abandonada"),
        (falta_de_vegetacao, "Falta de vegetação"),
        (lixo_residuos_solidos, "Lixo e resíduos sólidos"),
        (ocupacao_irregular, "Ocupação irregular"),
        (outros, "Outros"),
        (queda_bloco, "Queda de bloco"),
        (recalque, "Recalque")
    )
nome = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=tipos_opcoes, blank=True, null=True)
causas = models.ManyToManyField(Causa)
consequencias = models.ManyToManyField(Consequencia)

def __str__(self):
    return self.nome

class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = "Feições"

class Passivo(models.Model):
# Opcoes relevo
plano = 'PL'
ondulado = 'ON'
montanhoso = 'MO'

relevo_opcoes = (
    (plano, 'Plano'),
    (ondulado, 'Ondulado'),
    (montanhoso, 'Montanhoso')
)

# Opcoes terceira_faixa_localizacao
lado_direito = 'LD'
lado_esquerdo = 'LE'
inexistente = 'IN'
ambos = 'AM'

terceira_faixa_localizacao_opcoes = (
    (lado_direito, 'Lado Direito'),
    (lado_esquerdo, 'Lado Esquerdo'),
    (inexistente, 'Inexistente')
)

#opcoes pavimento
pavimento_asfautico = 'PA'
pavimento_concreto = 'PC'
nao_pavimentado =  'NP'
outro_pavimento = 'OP'
pista_rolamento_pavimento_opcoes = (
    (pavimento_asfautico, 'Pavimento Asfaltico'),
    (pavimento_concreto, 'Pavimento Concreto'),
    (nao_pavimentado,  'Nao Pavimentado'),
    (outro_pavimento, 'Outro Pavimento')
)

# opcoes lado
direito = 'D'
esquerdo = 'E'
indefinido = 'I'
ambos = 'A'

lado_opcoes = (
    (direito, 'Direito'),
    (esquerdo, 'Esquerdo'),
    (indefinido, 'Indefinido'),
    (ambos, 'Lado Direito e Esquerdo')
    )

# Opcoes Perigo
sem_perigo = '0'
perigo_potencial = '1'
perigo_iminente = '2'
perigo_instalado = '3'

nivel_gravidade_escolhas = (
    (sem_perigo, 'Sem Perigo'),
    (perigo_potencial, 'Perigo Potencial'),
    (perigo_iminente, 'Perigo Iminente'),
    (perigo_instalado, 'Perigo Instalado' )
)

# MODELO
data_inspecao = models.DateField('Data de inspeção',auto_now=False)

# LOCALIZAÇÃO
latitude = models.DecimalField('Latitude', max_digits=14, decimal_places=10, blank=False, null=True)
longitude = models.DecimalField('Longitude', max_digits=14, decimal_places=10, blank=False, null=True)
km_ponto = models.DecimalField('Km', blank=True, null=True,max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
lado = models.CharField('Lado de Ocorrência', blank=True, null=True,max_length=1,choices=lado_opcoes)
distancia_ao_eixo = models.CharField('Distância do Passivo ao Eixo',max_length=50,blank=True, null=True)
area_ocorrencia_faixa_dominio = models.NullBooleanField(blank=True, null=True, default=False)
area_ocorrencia_area_adjacente = models.NullBooleanField(blank=True, null=True, default=False)

# CARACTERIZAÇÃO DO SEGMENTO RODOVIÁRIO
largura_faixa_dominio_esquerda = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
largura_faixa_dominio_direita = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
pista_rolamento_numero = models.IntegerField('nº de pistas de rolamento', blank=True, null=True)
pista_rolamento_pavimento =  models.CharField(max_length=50,
                choices = pista_rolamento_pavimento_opcoes,
                default = pavimento_asfautico)
acostamento_presenca = models.NullBooleanField('Acostamento', default=False)
terceira_faixa_localizacao = models.CharField('Terceira Faixa / Localização', max_length=50,
                   choices = terceira_faixa_localizacao_opcoes,
                   default = inexistente)
relevo = models.CharField(max_length=50,
                   choices = relevo_opcoes,
                   default = plano)

# CARACTERIZAÇÃO DO PASSIVO
# feicao = models.OneToOneField(Feicao, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
feicao = models.ForeignKey(Feicao, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
dimensao_comprimento = models.DecimalField('Comprimento', max_digits=10, decimal_places=2,blank=True, null=True, default = None)
largura_faixa_dominio_total = models.DecimalField('Largura', max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
dimensao_profundidade = models.DecimalField('Profundidade', max_digits=10, decimal_places=2,blank=True, null=True, default = None)
risco_ao_usuario = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices = nivel_gravidade_escolhas, default = None,  blank=True, null=True)
risco_ao_patrimonio = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices = nivel_gravidade_escolhas, default = None,  blank=True, null=True)
risco_ao_ambiente = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices = nivel_gravidade_escolhas, default = None,  blank=True, null=True)
possiveis_causas = ChainedManyToManyField(
        Causa,
        horizontal=True,
        verbose_name='Possiveis Causas',
        chained_field="feicao",
        chained_model_field="feicao",
        )
provaveis_consequencias = ChainedManyToManyField(
                Consequencia,
                horizontal=True,
                verbose_name = 'Provaveis Consequências',
                chained_field="feicao",
                chained_model_field="feicao",
                )
localizacao = models.PointField(blank=True, null=True)
modelo_3d = models.FileField(upload_to='models/',blank=True, null=True, validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['zip'])])
modelo_3d_path =  models.CharField('Endereço do arquivo 3d (cloud.js)',max_length=128,blank=True, null=True)
croqui = models.ImageField('Croqui')
observacoes = models.TextField()
class Meta:
    db_table = 'passivo'





class Foto(models.Model):
descricao = models.CharField('Descrição',max_length=300, blank=True,     null=True, default = None)
image = ImageWithThumbsField(sizes=((100,130),(200,260)))
property = models.OneToOneField(Passivo,
                                related_name='fotos',
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)#, default='no-img.png')

class Meta:
    db_table = 'foto'
    verbose_name_plural = "Fotos"

    def __str__(self):
        return ("Fotos do passivo")



class Local(models.Model):
descricao = models.CharField(max_length=55, blank=True, null=True)
fk_passivo_passivo = models.OneToOneField(Passivo,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Meta:
    db_table = 'local'
```

Abaixo segue o codigo admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.apps import apps
from cadastramento.models import Feicao, Passivo, Causa, Consequencia, Foto
from sorl.thumbnail.admin import AdminImageMixin
import nested_admin
from leaflet.admin import LeafletGeoAdmin

class FotoInline(AdminImageMixin, admin.TabularInline):
model = Foto
extra = 0
class PassivoAdmin(AdminImageMixin,nested_admin.NestedModelAdmin):
model = Passivo
exclude = ['localizacao']


admin.site.register(Causa)
admin.site.register(Consequencia)
admin.site.register(Feicao)
admin.site.register(Passivo,PassivoAdmin)
```

Essas opções estavam funcionando, e parou de funcionar. Não me lembro se fiz alguma alteração e que veio a dar esse problema e não consigo encontrar o que deveria ser feito para que funcione.

Answer (score 0):

O problema era com a versão utilizada para o django-smart-selects. Estava usando a versão 0.24.0 que foi atualizada por algum motivo que eu não lembro. Mas a versão anterior era a 0.23.0 e ao fazer o downgrade voltou a funcionar.